# Resize image with intervention/image

Tags: laravel, image-upload, resize-image

I have a function to save the picture, and I need it to reduce the picture with the specified size. I decided to use the package `intervention/image`.
I installed the package with `composer require intervention/image`. Then I made changes to my function. In the end it turned out like this:

Controller:

```php
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
if ($request->hasFile('preview_image')) {
    $file = $request->file('preview_image');
    $namewithextension = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $name = explode('.', $namewithextension)[0];
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $uploadname = $name. '-' .DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(TRUE))->format('U-u') . '.' .$extension;
    $img = Image::make($file)->resize(240, 120);
    $article_block_image->preview_image = $img->save(public_path('public/article-block-image/preview' , $uploadname));
}
```

Model:

```php
public function getOriginPreviewImageUrl() {
   return $this->attributes['preview_image'];
}

public function getPreviewImageAttribute($value) {
    return Storage::exists($value) ? Storage::url($value) : null;
}
```

When I try to upload a picture I get this error.

> "message": "Can't write image data to path (D:\wamp64\www\test\public\public/article-block-image/preview)",
> "exception": "Intervention\Image\Exception\NotWritableException",
> "file": "D:\wamp64\www\test\vendor\intervention\image\src\Intervention\Image\Image.php",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$path = public_path('public/article-block-image/preview' . $uploadname);

Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(468, 249)->save($path);
```

Run command: `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: there is only a question, how to get the path to this picture now? in the get method, I have it null

Comment: in Laravel blade file < img src="{{asset('article-block-image/preview'.$uploadname ))"

Comment: this is understandable, but how to make it show the path to this image in the database, I have a field for this image `preview_image` in this field there is now `null`

Comment: send me pic where  you want to show the picture

Comment: I usually save images this way `$article_block_image->preview_image = $file->storeAs('public/article-block-image/preview', $uploadname);` my `preview_image` field is filled in and in the database we see the path to this image

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/TYcYxfn `main_image` I load the method described above, and `preview_image` is where `resize` is

Comment: you want to add the image in the database  for that create new variavble $article_image =/article-block-image/preview' .$uploadname;$article_block_image =$article_image;

Comment: so I threw off the screenshot, I want us to see the path to the preview image that we are currently loading

Comment: i tried `$article_block_image->preview_image = 'public/article-block-image/preview'. $uploadname;`  but it didn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238141/discussion-between-faran-and-meow).